# Android: insert row in database only once on database creation

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I have seen many questions on stackoverflow but none of the solutions work.
I want to add only 1 row in the database at the time on its creation and the only thing that the app does is update this row with new values.

I have tried writing an INSERT statement in the SQLiteOpenHelper class but it does not work. No row is inserted.

Code:

```
public class db_manager extends SQLiteOpenHelper{


private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "tally.db";
private static final String TABLE_TALLY = "tally";
private static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
private static final String COLUMN_VALUE = "value";


public db_manager(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, factory, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    String query = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_TALLY + "(" +
            COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            COLUMN_VALUE + " TEXT " +
            ");";
    db.execSQL(query);
    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO tally(value) VALUES (100)");
}
```

But if I try to insert a row from the mainActivity class using a method that I declared in the SQLiteOpenHelper class the row is inserted successfully but it add a new row every time I run the app..

Code:

```
// In mainActivity
DM = new db_manager(this,null,null,1);
DM.WriteFirst(10);

//In SQLiteOpenHelper class
    public void WriteFirst(int value){

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(COLUMN_VALUE, value);
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    db.insert(TABLE_TALLY, null, values);
    db.close();
}
```

I want to INSERT the row only once.

Comment: The INSERT statements works, but you have to ensure that `onCreate` is called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see where is the issue, you have a code that works and inserts successfully, provide more logic to check if the row exist before INSERT.

And the helper class should not insert the row anyway.

Comment: if the helper class shouldn’t insert a row then what logic should i use to insert a row once only on db creation ?

Comment: Simply run a select query and check if the row exist. If not insert its very simple